# Why cannot make test when installing OpenLDAP?

Tags: openldap, ubuntu-12.04

I've tried to install OpenLDAP with some steps I did before in other installation under the same conditions in Ubuntu 12.04

I've followed the manual that OpenLDAP has on line... But when I try to `make test` it fails in the first test... and checking the log of tests for errors it says:

```
error while loading shared libraries: libdb-5.3.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've searched on internet an the solution they said it's to add in the ./configure the paths for the libraries... so I did it:

`LD_LIBRARY_PATH="/usr/lib:/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/db5/lib:/usr/local/cyrus/lib" LDFLAGS="-L/usr/local/db5/lib -L/usr/local/cyrus/lib" CPPFLAGS="-I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/db5/include -I/usr/local/cyrus/include" ./configure -prefix=/usr/local/ldap --with-cyrus-sasl --with-tls`

but still nothing... any idea on how could I solve this??

Comment: Do you have a file on your system called `libdb-5.3.so`?

Comment: @DavidSchwartz yes it is in `/usr/local/db5/lib/libdb-5.3.so`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create file `/etc/ld.so.conf.d/db53.conf` with following line

```
/usr/local/db5/lib
```

Then run `ldconfig`.

Test again.

---

This put `/usr/local/db5/lib` into the system library search path.

Comment: this worked perfectly, could you explain how it works for future troubleshooting?? with this or other program?

Comment: Actually the last line is a simple explanation. The ld.so (dynamic linker/loader) holds a list of directories where libraries reside. The standard(pre-configured) path include `/lib`, `/usr/lib`, etc. In this case, libdb-5.3.so is not in any of those path. So we put in a config file to notify it. `ldconfig` is used to update the link cache(`/etc/ld.so.cache`), whenever there are changes to those information. So next time you run into similar situation, you can create a new `.conf` file specific for that library and run ldconfig again.

Comment: And the name of the file doesn't matter?? just that it has the path to the library I want is enough??

Comment: Partially matter, it must use `.conf` for extension. It is also a good practice to use meaningful name closely related to the lib/package.

Comment: just one more question (I hope), why it doesn't get the path when I specifically put it on the `./configure` line??

Comment: I am not sure about this particular configure, maybe that technique work for another package, but not this one. On the other hand, I remember seeing configure taking in additional lib path as options. Maybe you can check the options list with `./configure --help`. That should give you a complete option list.

Comment: If the same line works in another box, then maybe you have typo when you did it on this box?

Comment: I ask this because I ran that line in other box with the same OS and everything, and it didn't complain about it, I mean... is it better this way?? the other way is not secure about including the path??

Comment: It could not be a typo, cause I actually copied/pasted the line... that's why I got crazy... anyway, as soon as I can give you the bounty I'll do, thanks for your help, if something else comes to your mind about this weird problem, please let me know, thanks a lot!

Comment: On the other box, do following (1) `locate libdb-5.3.so` (2) `ldd <your compiled program>`

Comment: I located the library, but I'm not sure how to do `ldd`...

Comment: That output of that package should be `slapd` and `libldap`. Do `ldd slapd` and `ldd libldap`. I am checking if there are others.

Comment: I did it, and now??

Comment: What is the output? `ldd` show you what library(and the path) they are linked with. I am suspecting on the other box you are not linking with db5.3, but the one in `/usr/lib`

Comment: `linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007fff4032b000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ff0ca1e4000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff0c9e41000)
 /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ff0ca7bf000)`

Comment: That is not even showing the libdb. Lets do it another way, on both boxes, do `dpkg -l | grep libdb5`, then let me know the result.

Comment: `ii  libdb5.1                               5.1.25-11build1                         Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries [runtime]
ii  libdb5.1:i386                          5.1.25-11build1                         Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries [runtime]` first box


`ii  libdb5.1                                          5.1.25-11                               Berkeley v5.1 Database Libraries [runtime]` second box (the problematic one)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/7217/discussion-between-john-siu-and-poz2k4444)